# What's the right way to think about a CFG symbol with an infinite null derivation?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I'm curious about the right way to characterize symbol $A$ in a CFG like this one:

$$
\begin{align*}
A &\to A B\\
A &\to x\\
B &\to y\\
B &\to \varepsilon
\end{align*}
$$

$B$ is certainly nullable. However, should $A$ be considered nullable? It feels like the answer is probably "no" (and most first-follow implementations I've seen either agree or crash on this). However, you can derive an infinitely large parse tree for the null symbol sequence like $A \to A(A(A(...) B()) B()$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinitely large parse tree you propose does not represent the parse of any sentence, because its leaves are not all terminals.

A more precise statement would be that $A$ cannot derive the empty sentence. You can produce an arbitrarily long derivation of $A$ by repeatedly using the rules $A \to A B$ and $B \to \epsilon$ but none of those derivations is empty. Since the precise definition of "nullable" is "a non-terminal which can derive the empty sentence", $A$ is not nullable.

If a FIRST/FOLLOW implementation crashes on that input, then the implementation is buggy. The correct computations are:

$$\begin{align}
FIRST(A) &= \{x\} \\
FIRST(B) &= \{y, \epsilon\} \\
FOLLOW(A) &= \{y, \epsilon\} \\
FOLLOW(B) &= \{y, \epsilon\}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why is FOLLOW(B) just ϵ? I would have thought that since A(A(B(y))B(y)) is a valid parse tree that FOLLOW(B) should include y.

Comment: @chase: quite right, fixed.

Comment: @chase: by the way, it's usually easier to think in terms of derivations (which is how all the concepts are defined) than parse trees. The derivation I missed was $A\to AB\to ABB\to ABy$.

Answer (score 1):

A variable is nullable if you can derive the empty word from it. 
Hence, in your example, $A$ is not nullable. However, if you add a rule as, for example,

$$A \to B$$
then it is, as $A\Rightarrow B\Rightarrow \varepsilon$.